# Error al Enviar correo Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Como están?, tal vez alguien por aquí tuvo el mismo problema al enviar un correo configurando una cuenta de correo creada en hostgator para lo cual tengo lo siguiente dentro de mi aplicación

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
    'nuevostyle'=>[
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'gator4230.hostgator.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'user' => 'info@nuevostyle.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'tls' => true
],
'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
    'nuevostyle-profile' => [
        'transport' => 'nuevostyle',
        'from' => 'info@nuevostyle.com',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ]
],
```

cuando hago el envio me muestra el siguiente error

**SMTP Error: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException
Documentation API
If you want to customize this error message, create src\Template\Error\error500.ctp**

tal vez me este faltando realizar algo mas ayuda por favor Gracias!!!!

Comment: Puede ser obvio... pero el servidor de correos corre en localhost?
Podrías revisar el log del servidor de correo si es que tienes acceso

Comment: a que te refieres que reviso donde esta corriendo la apliacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estuvo que dentro de mi servidor local (es decir mi hosting no permitía el acceso de la cuenta estando dentro del servidor local) asi que hice pruebas desde el hosting y todo bien, claro esta que la configuración estuvo bien